# Javafx Jfoenix input validation change error message color

Tags: validation, javafx, javafx-8, jfoenix

As I mentioned in the title I need to change the color of the error message. By default it shows in black.

[image: example image]

**Here is my code so far :**

```
RequiredFieldValidator rfv = new RequiredFieldValidator();
        branch_name_txt.getValidators().add(rfv);
        rfv.setMessage("This field is not optional.");
        rfv.setIcon(new GlyphIcons().setFontAwesomeIconGlyph('\uf00d', Color.RED, 20.0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Googling a while I found this [comment response on a youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MU0MCdk3i7s#comment-renderer-edit-z13sthw4ztejcx0lv22bynwprqahjh3vz.1495676687442330)

Conclusion:

```
.error * {
    -fx-text-fill: ce-yellow;
}
```

**Edit**: It seems that jfoenix version `1.6.0` no longer uses `.error` to style this tiny label below the text field. **Use** `.error-label` **instead.**